# from one table to another table and order adding PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get the customerid from `customer` table to `ordertracking` table.
-But- The adding of the order also needs the product information it gets from the orderform. I've tried few ways, but can't get it to work. 
Also another strange thing:

```
//connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");  

//check if already customer
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email='$email'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rows) 
    {
      echo '<br>Welcome back ' . $name .' '. $surname. '<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        //if new customer, add to database
        $customer = "INSERT INTO customer (customerid, name, surname, email, city, GETalcode, phonenumber) VALUES ('', '$name', '$surname', '$email', '$city', '$postalcode', '$phonenumber')";
        if (!mysql_query($customer,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        echo "New customer added" . "<br />";
        echo '<br>Welcome as our new customer ' . $name . ' '. $surname;

        mysql_close($connection);   
    }

//connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");

//get customer id
????????????????????
    //add new order
    $ordertracking = "INSERT INTO ordertracking (orderid, customerid, productid, brand, model, price, amount, totalcost) VALUES ('', '$customerid', '$productid', '$brand', 'model', 'price', 'amount', 'totalcost')";
    if (!mysql_query($ordertracking,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        echo "New order added" . "<br />";

        mysql_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT customerid FROM customer WHERE email='$email'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 $customerid=$row['customerid'];
}
```

use this $customerid when inserting into the ordertracking table

Comment: aaaaaaand....... It works! Thank you very much for the script. I now get customerid in ordertracking. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just like you got the customer data in first place:

```
$customerid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT customerid FROM customer WHERE email='$email'")); 
echo $customerid[0];
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I echo it out it shows `Resource id #5`. But in customer table customerid is 2 not 5.

`$customerid = mysql_query("SELECT customerid FROM customer WHERE email='$email'");
echo $customerid;`

And in the ordertracking table it still shows '0'. Why?

Comment: Of course, you still need to fetch the result, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_insert_id()` after the insert or `$rows['customerid']` after the select.

Comment: sorry thought you make a $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = "INSERT INTO customer (customerid, name, surname, email, city,
             GETalcode, phonenumber) VALUES 
            ('', '$name', '$surname', '$email', '$city',
             '$postalcode', '$phonenumber')";
        if (!mysql_query($customer,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        else
        {
            $customer_id =mysql_insert_id();
        }
```

// then insert into order tables

Comment: thank you for the script, but pardhu's script is working. Anyways, thank you